# best mysql deployment solution to support different applications with different mysqld backend server configuration

Tags: mysql

`mysql` is a common database and it supports kinds of configuration and tune parameters such as `character_set_server`, `innodb_log_file_size` and so on. These backend parameters are set under e.g. `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` configuration file and below the `[mysqld]` section, and take effect after `service mysql restart`.

There exists a situation where a single mysql server is providing database service for more than one application (on the same physical machine), and each of the applications may has its own officially recommended backend parameter settings.

However, it may happens when the parameters of different applications differ from each other and it may become worse when there are conflicts between application settings, for example, app A needs `utf8` as the character encoding method and app B is using another one.

So, is there any mysqld configuration method to support this situation, or the right way is to start multiple mysql instances with each tuned for one application.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Running anything but `utf8mb4` in 2022 is asking for problems you don't need.

Comment: These are server defaults. Remember you can override these at the table or even column level if necessary.

Comment: Character set settings in particular can be set at the server, database, table, column *and* connection level. There's no need to edit the server settings for that, and each application can and should explicitly specify their character set expectations at the appropriate level. Something like log file size should *not* be application dependent but entirely up to the server admin. — Do you have a more specific question given these clarifications…?

Comment: some of the settings include `character-set-server`, `default-storage-engine`, `max_allowed_packet`, `transaction-isolation`, `binlog_format`, `sql_mode`, `innodb_default_row_format`. It's ok to find a greatest common divisor of all settings. what i want to know is the way to set the parameters for every database or table, so i can follow the official installation guide and do not need to dive into the mysql details. It's hard for a layman to know the side effect of a parameter that do not appear in the official recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I found the [mysqld_multi](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld-multi.html) solution from mysql official site solved my problems, which can start multiple mysqld processes and each one could has its own configurations.